# create multiple page pdf from asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation

I was trying to create a pdf dynamically and send it by attaching in the mail.
This is my code and it works perfectly for me.

```
   public ActionResult sendmail()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0.0f);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
        doc.Open(); //open doc for editing
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("First Paragraph"));
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Second Paragraph"));
        writer.CloseStream = false; //important
        doc.Close(); //build the doc.

        ms.Position = 0;

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.Host = "provider.com";
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("credentialmailid", "password");


        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage()
        {
            From = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com")
        };
        mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@gmail.com"));
        mailMessage.Subject = "Pdf attached";            
        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "pdfname.pdf"));
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        return RedirectToAction("index");
    }
```

Now my issue is : Document that I have to send is a purchase confirmation . it will have 3 pages. Many headings and styles will be there in it.

also some values I have to pass dynamically like who purchased it and date like wise a lot datas should pass dynamically

How to do this? I thought to create an Html of pdf file to be send and use something like this add parameters dynamically...

```
        string mailpath = Server.MapPath("~/Mail/HtmlOF_pdfToSend.html");
        string mailbody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(mailpath);
        mailbody = mailbody.Replace("##CompanyName", "Bhavin Merchant");
        mailbody = mailbody.Replace("##BusinessType", "Bhavin business");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist You have to add iTextSharp dll then u have to add some packages :

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
using iTextSharp.text.xml;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
```

then as per your question. you want to pass dynamically values so i post some syntax as example :

```
       // Create a Document object
        var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);
        var output = new MemoryStream();

    // Create a new PdfWriter object, specifying the output stream
    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

   // Open the Document for writing
        document.Open();
```

Suppose you have header in your pdf documnet so syntax will be :

```
        var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/images/it.jpg"));
        logo.SetAbsolutePosition(300, 750);
        document.Add(logo);
```

If you want to add phrase:

```
        Phrase titl = new Phrase("\nE-Ticket\n");
        titl.Font.SetStyle(Font.BOLD);
        document.Add(titl);
```

Add lines :

```
   Phrase titl1 = new   Phrase("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
        titl1.Font.SetStyle(Font.BOLD);
        document.Add(titl1);
```

Change the style of text :

Here you can change the font style & color.

```
       Phrase title = new Phrase("Booking Date-" + txtDate1.Text + "\n");
        title.Font.SetStyle(Font.BOLD);
        document.Add(title);
```

If you want to add pdf table:-dt is data table.

```
      PdfPTable UserInfoTable = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
        PdfPRow row = null;
       UserInfoTable.AddCell(--add cell----);
       document.Add(UserInfoTable);
```

Close the Document - this saves the document contents to the output stream

```
        document.Close();


       Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=Receipt-{0}.pdf", "hello"));
        Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray())
```

Here I paste some example code as your question.

Comment: I mean there will be colors to some texts in it and also draw lines . so still this is the convenient way? Text is huge..like terms and conditions. Adding this much in code behind is good?

Comment: Actually it is the terms and the conditions and other business details. So Is it good method?

Comment: are you asking , how to generate pdf dynamically or asking about dynamically generate pdf , is it convenient or not ?

Comment: I am sorry for not specific. As I told in the question, I am getting a test type pdf correctly. but to get a pdf with huge texts and styles this is the convenient idea?if not is there any other method?and if this is the correct method for my requirements, how can I drow lines and add styles to texts ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89375/discussion-between-anurag-jain-and-bhavin-bhaskaran).

Comment: Is the convenient or not its totally depend on your requirement.  Second think is , how to style the text . I answered you.  how to add lines , I edited the answer again please look.

Answer (score 1):

You can add more pages to the document like this:

```
 doc.Open(); //open doc for editing
 doc.Add(new Paragraph("First Paragraph"));
 doc.newPage();
 doc.add(new Paragraph("This is a new page =)"));
```